# Can I use waste water from kitchen for plants?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, greywater

Can I use the waste water mixed with dish washing liquid from kitchen for watering my garden?

Comment: What sort of dish washing liquid are you using?

Comment: *Most* hand-dishwashing soaps are OK. I'd look at the ingredient list of a machine washing detergent **hard** before putting it on my tomatoes. A small scale test on a potted plant such as basil might be a good way to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you remove all the solids first after washing your dishes as they might attract flies and rodents, you may still have a problem with sodium being added to your soil. So the type of liquid detergent is important.

http://ecologycenter.org/factsheets/greywater-cleaning-products/

> 3. Household Cleaners / Dish Soap / All Purpose Liquid Cleaner:
>
> Recommended:
>
> ```
> Oasis dishwash/all-purpose cleaner for handwashing dishes, body & shampoo
> Ecos: Creamy Cleanser; Parsley Plus; Furniture Polish; Window Kleener; Floor Kleener; Carpet Shampoo
> ```
>
> Limit:
>
> ```
> Bon Ami (it is biodegradable and has no perfumes, dyes, chlorine, or fragrance, but does contain sodium carbonate)
> Ecos: Shower Kleener (sodium gluconate, sodium citrate)
> Dr. Bronners: Sal Suds (sodium laurel sulfate)
> Citra Dish (sodium chloride)
> Ecover Dishwashing Liquid (sodium laureth sulfate, sodium chloride)
> ```
>
> Avoid:
>
> ```
> Ajax (sodium carbonate, bleach, fragrance, color);
> Comet (bleach, +?);
> Ajax (?);
> Ivory (?);
> Palmolive (?);
> Joy (?);
> Dawn (?)
> ```